# How to orient pan tilt kinect "head" and the turtlebot arm

Tags: ros, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot and I am updating it with a turtlebot arm and the pan tilt kinect head (thanks to Patrick Goebel). Anyway, the instructions for both, each separately have the arm and the head on the top level of the turtlebot. Has anyone got any good suggestions for an updated orientation that would be a good location for both the arm and the pan tilt head?
If both are on the top, it will interfere with the kinect area of vision.
Thanks in advance for the suggestions.
-Scott

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11468/how-to-orient-pan-tilt-kinect-%22head%22-and-the-turtlebot-arm/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Scott,

Congrats on setting up the TurtleBot arm and head.  Yeah, I had the same thoughts as you and though I haven't tried moving either the arm or head yet, a few ideas that came to mind are: (1) mount the arm one level below the head.  This way the gripper would still be visible to the Kinect but the rest of the arm would be out of the way.  It might also let the gripper reach the ground so that your TB could pick up stuff off the floor.  (2) Keep the arm on the top level but move it to one side or the other so that it is not directly in front of the camera.  TF can handle the changed geometry once you update your URDF/Xacro model.  And (3), put the head on longer stand-offs so it can see better over the arm.  This could be combined with either (1) or (2).

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the original robot with the arm, [Mini Maxwell](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mini_max), I mounted the Kinect up pretty high over the arm (which is located to interact with objects on the ground). Remember taht the kinect will have a deadspot about 0.5m long, so you need to be at least that far away from the objects you want to manipulate or you won't have point cloud data for the objects.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1